# iCloud backup fails on iOS 6

Tags: icloud, backup, ios

Have recently noticed my ios6 running iPhone hasn't done an iCloud backup since November. Could there be a new icloud api that would prevent ios6 devices from backing up properly? It appears to fail even when started manually. With no particular error message of course.
Did anyone have a similar problem?
Maybe someone can tell me the icloud log location? I've only found a preference plist with 
BackStateInfo - error, code 1, domain MBEroorDomain, localizedDescription "Service crashed".
The backup fails on a different network as well.

Comment: Which iPhone is it?

Comment: iPhone 5 running ios6

Answer (score 1):

That's the kind of thing software updates typically fix. Since it's an iPhone 5, you could try updating to iOS 8.4.1 today, or wait until iOS 9.0 launches in a couple of weeks. Just go to Settings->General->Software Update. I can't guarantee that updating will solve your problem, but you should update anyway for many reasons: new and better design, new features, bug fixes, security updates, and many other things.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My question was rather a search for some non-radical solutions, since it would seem possible.